# How to remove duplicates values and create a table view section in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, dictionary

Thanks for the help guys, I have a dictionary with an array of dictionary.
My objective is to sort out an array that is read from a plist file, out of one inner dictionary value. The values are String type and returns an array with duplicate values. This returned array has a total count of 30 values (elements) that can be categorized in 6 values. I need to somehow create an array out these 6 values so I can use it on my tableView Data Source, numberOfSectionsInTableView:

I looked into map() and filter() but could not walk away with any solution. My codes are;

```
 // setupLoading called from viewDidLoad()
 func setupLoading() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle
    let bundlePath = path.pathForResource("KempfRef", ofType: "plist")
    let dict: NSDictionary? = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath!)
    let plistArray: NSArray = dict!["KempfRef"] as NSArray

    for innerDict in plistArray as Array {


             let kempf: KempfFiber = KempfFiber() // Model
             kempf.name = innerDict["Name"] as String
             kempf.detail = innerDict["Detail"] as String
             kempf.imageName = innerDict["ImageName"] as String
             kempf.specGrav = innerDict["SpecGrav"] as String
             kempf.toughness = innerDict["Toughness"] as String
             kempf.pdfFile = innerDict["PDF"] as String
             //println("DESCRIPTION: \(kempf.description())")

             var theType = innerDict["Type"] as String             
             var kempfTypes = [String](arrayLiteral: theType)

             println("theType")
  }
```

// Here are the println of theType
The Types are:

```
BERKempf
BERKempf
BERKempf
BERKempf
CHRYBERKempf
CHRYBERKempf
CHRYBERKempf
CORUNKempf
CORUNKempf
CORUNKempf
CORUNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
GARNKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
OTHERKempf
SPINEKempf
SPINEKempf
SPINEKempf
SPINEKempf
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `kempf` vsriable that you create. Which field do you want to use for your sections?

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks. I am trying to utilize the values returned by "Type" key. Then I created var kempfTypes array which I would like to use for my section. I know I have not shown anything here because I wasn't able to get anything from what I've tried. Can you offer like a suggestion on what I should do or functions to use perhaps?

Comment: I would create another dictionary with a string key (which will be your type) and an array of `KempfFiber` as the values.  Then when you get a type  you retrieve the array from the dictionary.  If it is nil then create a new array, add the `kempf` object to it, otherwise just add the `kempf` object to the existing array.  You can then get the keys as an array for your sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another dictionary with a string key (which will be your type) and an array of KempfFiber as the values. Then when you get a type you retrieve the array from the dictionary. If it is nil then create a new array, add the kempf object to it, otherwise just add the kempf object to the existing array. You can then get the keys as an array for your sections.

Something like this (where `kempfData` and `sectionKeys` are properties of your current class -

```
self.kempfData=[String:[KempfFiber]]    

for innerDict in plistArray as Array {
    let kempf: KempfFiber = KempfFiber() // Model
    kempf.name = innerDict["Name"] as String
    kempf.detail = innerDict["Detail"] as String
    kempf.imageName = innerDict["ImageName"] as String
    kempf.specGrav = innerDict["SpecGrav"] as String
    kempf.toughness = innerDict["Toughness"] as String
    kempf.pdfFile = innerDict["PDF"] as String

    var theType = innerDict["Type"] as String     

    var kempfArray=self.kempfData[theType]

    if (kempfArray ==nil) {
        kempfArray =[Kempf]()     
    }

    kempfArray!.append(kempf)
    self.kempfData[theType]= kempfArray

  }

  self.sectionKeys=Array(self.kempfData.keys)
```

Now you can return `sectionKeys.count` as your section count.
Your `numberOfRowsInSection` will be

```
 let sectionData=self.kempfData[self.sectionKeys[indexPath.section]]

 if (sectionData != nil) {
     return sectionData!.count
 }
 else {
     return 0
 }
```

Similarly, in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can access the data using

```
let sectionData=self.kempfData[self.sectionKeys[indexPath.section]]

if (sectionData != nil) {
     let kempf=sectionData[indexPath.row]
     // Configure your cell...
}
else {
    // Something bad happened
}
```

You may want to sort the `self.sectionKeys` array after you create it, so that your sections are in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank You very much, That was brilliant! That is exactly what I needed. I will be away from my machine tonight but will implement this maybe around 3:00 am. I will let you know. How do I accept this or up vote the answer?